# Facebook Login permission denied

Tags: facebook, sdk

I'm trying to implement facebook login on my site, but I'm stuck here.
I need user's email.
I ask for permissions. If permissions granted everything is fine.
If the button "Not Now"(permissions denied) is pressed and he try to login again on the site, the permissions pop-up will no longer appear.
How to show the "pop-up" again for users who did not accept the permissions?Thank you!

```
    <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 
?>

<?php
require_once '/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
// start session

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '12345','12345' );

// login helper with redirect_uri

    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('urlcallback' );
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=name,email' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbuname = $graphObject->getProperty('username');  // To Get Facebook Username
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = $fbuname;
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
    //echo 'email:'.$femail;
} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'public_profile,email,user_friends')) . '">Login</a>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution add in public function getLoginUrl:

```
$params['auth_type'] = 'rerequest';
```